# Improving topology around a boolean

Tags: modeling

Any suggestions how to improve the topology of this?
I'm new to hardsurface modelling so I can only think of splitting up the faces around the boolean with the knife tool. But maybe there are better ways?

[image]

Here is a link to my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1epnKa2cP17_iCJ3274Mw3KbiCc_UWCcr/view?usp=sharing

Thx!

Comment: Enable Auto Smooth or you would have to change topology like get rid of n-gons ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho you should not use *Boolean* for this kind of object. You could rework the topology manually but it will be faster to redo from scratch (also, work with less vertices and use a *Subdivision Surface* if it's ok for your project).

But a quick fix for the bad shading is to select all the faces that are co-planar:

[image]

Then select the first segment of the bevels all around, like this one:

[image]

Then <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to flatten the faces and the segments together on Y. It will make the bad shading disappear as Blender doesn't try to smooth anymore between these faces:

[image]

Or you can use a *Weighted Normal* modifier, so that it won't smooth between large and small faces, but you need to create a bevel along the screen window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks moonboots, the weighted normal modifier solved most of the problem!